# As a new tablet user, how can I bring the quality of my writing on a tablet closer to what it is on physical paper?

Tags: drawing-tablet

I recently bought a Wacom Intuos art, I'm absolutely terrible at it, compared to a mouse I just see a +20% improvement :

[image]

Guys on the net are using it and it's so smooth! I trained for about 4 hours, but no significant improvement! 100 bucks wasted?

PS : I'm pretty decent at drawing with a physical pen.

Comment: Well 5 hours is a pretty short time. Anyway what application do you use some apps like to smooth out the result.

Comment: I'm using gimp and ms paint on Windows 10.

Comment: Try krita first

Comment: hello joojaa, I also tried the windows Sketechpad, it's like day and night. Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? ty.

Comment: Good thing you added a PS. because my Handwriting looks like that

Comment: what is your question, exactly?

Comment: You could also try MyPaint which is Open Source - and simple to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some programs do not sample the movement of the mouse with a high enough frequency. Try using a software that is meant for tablet drawing you can try:

- Krita (free)
- Autodesk Sketchbook
- ...

Answer (score 3):

It often takes a week or so to adapt to a tablet and truly be comfortable with it. The disconnect between where you write and where you look takes some adjustment above and beyond mouse use.

Wacom tablets are *rarely* "buggy", but that's not impossible. Any issues with the tablet are generally due to the driver, not the hardware. Ensure you have the newest driver, which will almost *never* be the driver you got on a CD, always check the web site ---> [WACOM](http://www.wacom.com/en-ca/support/product-support/drivers).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the difference in friction can be annoying. I have some students who are more comfortable when they put a piece of paper over the tablet as it recreates the feeling of physical paper without compromising what you are doing with the tablet. Might be worth a shot, along with other posters' answers!

Comment: I also use the paper trick regularly. I can confirm it definitely works!